# How to retrieve data in python from angular input?

Tags: python, angular, flask, frontend, backend

This is my first post and quite a noob question.
I'm doing final project for CS50. I'm interested mainly in frontend so I've been learning Angular(16). I did most of the frontend, but now I have to do a backend part. I know basic concepts of backend and SQL.
What I'm trying to do is a login & register authentication and with PostgreSQL to store users.

But the problem I'm having is, how to get data from user in Angular to Python?

I'll be happy for any help I can get. Thank you!

At the moment this is just a simple register html, just so I can learn how to connect frontend and backend.

register.component.html:

```
<div class="column" [formGroup]="registerFormGroup">
  <div class="level">
    <div class="level-item">
      <mat-form-field hintLabel="Max 20 characters">
        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
        <input
          id="username"
          matInput
          #input
          maxlength="10"
          formControlName="username"
          placeholder="Your Username"
          name="username"
        />
        <mat-hint align="end">{{ input.value.length }}/10</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column" [formGroup]="registerFormGroup">
  <div class="level">
    <div class="level-item">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Enter your password</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="password" matInput />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column" [formGroup]="registerFormGroup">
  <div class="level">
    <div class="level-item">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>ReEnter your password</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="password2" matInput />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="level">
    <div class="level-item">
      <button class="button is-primary" type="submit" (click)="register()">
        Register
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And TypeScript component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router){}

  public registerFormGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: [''],
    password: [''],
    password2: ['']
  })
  register() {
    this.http.post<any>("http://127.0.0.1:5000/register", this.registerFormGroup.value).subscribe((response) =>{
      this.registerFormGroup.reset()
      this.router.navigate(["login"])})
  }
}
```

Now I'm not sure if I'm even doing this right, I was looking at some tutorials on how to create backend in Python.
So I have **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from .user import user

    app.register_blueprint(user, url_prefix="/")

    return app
```

user.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, request


user = Blueprint("user", __name__)


@user.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])  # type: ignore
def login():

    return


@user.route("/logout")  # type: ignore
def logout():
    return


@user.route("/register", methods=["POST", "GET"])  # type: ignore
def register():
    data = request.form
    print(data)
    return
```

and main.py

```
from backend import create_app


app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**init**.py and user.py are in serpent folder called backend.

**EDIT:**

Found a solution, if anyone had the same problem/question. It was with .get_json():

```
@user.route("/register", methods=["POST", "GET"])  # type: ignore
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()

        username = data["username"]
        password = data["password"]
        password2 = data["password2"]

        if len(username) < 4:
            return Response(status=400)
        elif len(password) < 6:
            return Response(status=400)

        elif password != password2:
            return Response(status=400)

        else:
            db.execute(
                "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= %s", [username])
            user = db.fetchone()
            if user:
                # user exists can't register
                return Response(status=400)
            else:
                passHash = generate_password_hash(password)
                db.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO users (username, pass) VALUES (%s, %s)", (username, passHash))
                database_connection.commit()
            return Response(status=200)

    print()
    return Response(status=200)
```